# Explanation of Mathematics for Retrofitting Word Vectors

Tags: word-embeddings

The code from this paper on [Retrofitting Word Vectors with Semantic Lexicons](http://www.manaalfaruqui.com/papers/naacl15-retrofitting.pdf) works really well. The method works with the output of any embedding model. I am trying to understand the mathematics. How is the update rule developed and what is the colon notation used? Any pointers to intro resources on helping to understand the math would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The colon is just set notation. For example,
$$j:(i, j) \in E$$
below the summation signs simply says, sum over all j such that (i, j) is in the edge set. Taking the derivative and setting it to zero should be obvious enough to derive the update rule.

Comment: do you know of a good starting resource for a beginner with this sort of maths?

Comment: This is not math, just notation, you can look them up here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation